# How to use transaction with "async" functions in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, asynchronous, transactions

When `async def call_test(request):` called `async def test():` as shown below (I use **Django==3.1.7**):

```py
async def test():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print("Test")

async def call_test(request):

    await test() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Call_test")
```

There was no error displaying the proper result below on console:

```
Test
Test
Test
```

But, when I put `@transaction.atomic()` on `async def test():` as shown below:

```py
@transaction.atomic # Here
async def test():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print("Test")

# ...
```

The error below occurred:

> django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

So, I put `@sync_to_async` under `@transaction.atomic()` as shown below:

```py
@transaction.atomic
@sync_to_async # Here
async def test():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print("Test")

# ...
```

But, the same error below occurred:

> django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this
> from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

So, I put `@sync_to_async` on `@transaction.atomic()` as shown below:

```py
@sync_to_async # Here
@transaction.atomic
async def test():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print("Test")

# ...
```

But, other error below occurred:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited   handle = None  #
> Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs. RuntimeWarning:
> Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

So, how can I use transaction with `async` functions in Django?

Comment: It strikes me that you might want a task running in the background rather than an async task?

Comment: Also did you try inverting your wrappers? E.g. putting transaction.atomic 1st?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. The difference was, that I needed to use an atomic transaction as an asynchronous context manager. After reading, that few people wrote it is impossible in the current version of Django `4.2.4`. Started to investigate the code base myself.

The first thing I noticed, `transaction.atomic()` does not implement logic itself. It is just returning `Atomic` context decorator.
This decorator has 3 methods that are important to handle:

- `__init__` atomic() passes arguments to it, so we have to handle them.
- `__enter__` and `__exit__` which are important for context manager to work.

```py
class Atomic(ContextDecorator):
    ...
    def __init__(self, using, savepoint, durable):
    ...
    def __enter__(self):
    ...
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    ...

def atomic(using=None, savepoint=True, durable=False):
    # Bare decorator: @atomic -- although the first argument is called
    # `using`, it's actually the function being decorated.
    if callable(using):
        return Atomic(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, savepoint, durable)(using)
    # Decorator: @atomic(...) or context manager: with atomic(...): ...
    else:
        return Atomic(using, savepoint, durable)
```

For asynchronous context managers to work, we need to implement `__aenter__` and `__aexit__`. With this in mind, I came up with working solution:

```py
from django.db.transaction import Atomic
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

class AsyncAtomicContextManager(Atomic):
    def __init__(self, using=None, savepoint=True, durable=False):
        super().__init__(using, savepoint, durable)

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await sync_to_async(super().__enter__)()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        await sync_to_async(super().__exit__)(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

Which can be used as a standard async context manager:

```py
async def test():
    async with AsyncAtomicContextManager():
        ...
```

Then you can make a decorator from this:

```py
def aatomic(fun, *args, **kwargs):
    async def wrapper():
        async with AsyncAtomicContextManager():
            await fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@aatomic
async def test():
    ...
```

Comment: this is the solution, I tested it and it works great! looking at your solution, it should just be rolled into django source code, I would suggest to bring this up to their github. Good work!

Comment: [This is the issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33882) in the Django feature tracker where it may someday happen:

Comment: This is risky. Since worker tasks running in an asyncio event loop share a thread (and hence a database session), when code inside the `AsyncAtomicContextManager` block yields with `await`, other async code _outside_ that context manager could execute _within the same transaction_. That means you could accidentally commit, or accidentally roll back, from non-local code outside the contextmanager.  True async transactions with this pattern would require the contextmanager to maintain separate database sessions -- it's a lot harder, and probably why Django hasn't done it yet.

Comment: @user85461 I looked into this problem. There is no risk of accidentally committing. Connection keeps track of any transaction blocks and makes save points. Committing is made after all transaction blocks are exited. Which also doesn't seem right. Accidental rollbacks are a risk thought. In my use cases, running two transactions in a single worker is impossible. I have different reasons for asyncronic manager. Still, it's a good point. Anyway, I think I can improve this code with a little more work. I will try and run some tests, then edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found [the documentation of Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/#queries-the-orm) says below:

> Transactions do not yet work in async mode. If you have a piece of code that needs transactions behavior, we recommend you write that piece as a single synchronous function and call it using sync_to_async().

So, `@transaction.atomic()` cannot be used with `async` functions in the order version **Django 3.1.7** as well.