# How to use transaction with async function in Django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-models, django-views

I'm attempting to retrieve a list of orders from a PostgreSQL database using an asynchronous function, but I'm encountering a RuntimeError with the message 'You cannot use ATOMIC_REQUESTS with async views.' I've tried debugging the code and noticed that the get function in Orders is not being called at all. I've also looked through the Django documentation but couldn't find any relevant information. Can someone assist me with resolving this issue?

Here is code

```
class Utils:
    @sync_to_async
    def get_orders(self):
        orders = Order.objects.all()
        return [orders]

    @sync_to_async
    def get_sellers(self):
        sellers = Seller.objects.all()
        return [sellers]

class Orders(View, Utils):

    async def get(self, request):
        orders = asyncio.ensure_future(self.get_orders())

        await asyncio.wait([orders])
        print(orders.result())

        return render(request, 'orders.html')
```

Here is logs of error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
  File "C:\Хранилище говна\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner    
  File "C:\Хранилище говна\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Хранилище говна\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 192, in _get_response
    wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
  File "C:\Хранилище говна\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 350, in make_view_atomic
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: You cannot use ATOMIC_REQUESTS with async views.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use transaction with "async" functions in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575922/how-to-use-transaction-with-async-functions-in-django)
As mentioned in that question/answer the docs say "Transactions do not yet work in async mode. If you have a piece of code that needs transactions behavior, we recommend you write that piece as a single synchronous function and call it using sync_to_async()."

Answer (score 1):

In setting you might find option named "ATOMIC_REQUEST" (usually it placed in DATABASE settings) and turn it to False.